# Android main activity displays only once if the app is not closed

Tags: android

I have an app that will display the logo first, then it will go to the home activity of the app. Just like some other apps, if the app(my app) is not completely closed, even the user re-open the app(my app), the logo should not be displayed again. I mean if the user presses home button of the phone or switches to other apps, the phone will stop the app(my app) and switch back to its home or open other apps, the app(my app) is not closed. So when the user clicks the app's(my app) icon to open the stopped app, the logo should not be displayed but the home activity of the app.

I guess this should be done by using two activities. Then after 4s, it will direct the user from the logo to the home activity of the app. However, if I press home button of the phone or switch to other apps then go back to my app, the logo will be shown again but not the home activity of the app. So how to deal with this problem, or the logo activity can be done in different way?

Comment: If you leave the app from `Main2Activity`, then that's what you should see when coming back

Comment: Tip: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: I have found a way to fix this, which is using the Immersive Full-Screen Mode, however, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I trust your ability to search for how to accomplish that

Comment: since the activity's onCreate method is only called when the activity is created, the handler.postDelayed call will only happen when the activity is created. if i'm understanding your question, you want postDelayed to happen more often than that. so, you might find it useful to put the handler.postDelayed call into a method which occurs later in the activity's lifecycle (e.g. onResume).

Comment: I mean if the user presses back button on the navigation bar, it will go back to the home of the phone. Then if the user clicks the app's icon, the logo activity should not be shown, however, it still shows up, even I have `finish()`.